# how to read my laptop's SATA ports information from hwinfo

Tags: sata

Thanks to anyone that will help. I am a newbie, please forgive my inexperience.

I need to be 100% sure that my laptop's SATA ports are **ALL** SATA II because I want to buy stuff like SATA cables, HDD/SSD caddy etc.

[image]

According to hwinfo I have 4 SATA ports but I only know about 2 of them,

a) The SATA port for HDD

b) The slim SATA for CD/DVD

**Questions**

1) Where are the other 2 ports?

2) If "SATA Host Controller" > "Interface speed supported" says Gen. II, does it mean **all** of my SATA ports?

3) If "Port#4" > "Current interface speed" says Gen. I, does it mean the device?

**My laptop info**

Packard Bell Easynote TJ75

Chipset Intel HM55

Motherboard images

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most chipsets support 4 or more SATA ports but in general only 2 are implemented in a laptop. The setting means all ports on the "host" are capable of SATA II, the current setting that shows SATA I is probably your optical drive as most are only SATA I anyway.

Comment: Everything you need to know is in [this manual](http://tim.id.au/laptops/packardbell/easynote%20tj75%20tj76%20tj77%20tj78.pdf). It appears, as @acejavelin suggests, that the two other interfaces in the chipset are unconnected. If you are comfortable with hardware modifications, you may be able to solder extra connectors. As for SATA cables, [these tests](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/SATA-3Gb-s-vs-6Gb-s-Cable-Performance-Revisited-183/) show that it makes no difference.

Comment: acejavelin thank you so much!
That means I can buy a caddy, put another SSD in, and have 2 SSD with SATA2. Now I only need to find out about the speed of the 2 mini PCIe (top-left in 2nd motherboard picture). PS If you create an answer I'll accept it.